# react-map-gl makes request to its api everytime the component is rendered

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

I am using `react-map-gl` Mapbox for map but it seems to make requests to mapbox api every time the component is rendered. How can I prevent this?
My component

```
<ReactMapGL
        mapboxApiAccessToken={accessToken}
        {...viewport}
        onViewportChange={nextViewport => setViewport(nextViewport)}
    >
        {markers(list, chooseHandler)}
</ReactMapGL>
```

Comment: what request ??? explain please

Comment: to its own mapbox api

Comment: ok currently working on project with react mabox using this library  https://github.com/urbica/react-map-gl but i didn't noticed the issue. maybe this has to do how the component work .

Comment: Could you check this site? where you could click on some side nav and go back to the page, the map re-renders https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/

Comment: i don't know why you care about this but when change the page and go back to it the map will re-render which will recall mapbox api .

Comment: That is exactly what is happening in my site as well thats why

Comment: @LokeshBajracharya I encountered a similar issue on one of my projects. I use a Bottom Navigation from MUI and everytime I change the page, it re-fetches data... How did you solve it in the meantime?

Comment: I ended up using leaflet on that project

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the same problem and could finally solve the issue. There is a property reuseMaps that takes care of this.

https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/api-reference/map#reusemaps

If reuseMaps is set to true, when a map component is unmounted, the underlying Map instance is retained in memory. The next time a map component gets mounted, the saved instance is reused.

Edit: I saw that you switched to leaflet anyways. Hope it helps a future developer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer 2Up1Down, it has been very useul.

However, I have noticed that when using reuseMaps, even the map on different pages get retained in memory and are displayed, even though they don't have the same props for example the `initialViewState`.
Then, only when I interact with the Map, the props get updated. But that's not a desirable behaviour since the first thing I see is a map with the previous map props and initial position.

I am looking for a solution where **only maps with same props are retained in memory**

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm currently using reuseMaps when a map is loaded and saved on movement, but I set reuseMaps false when a query is used (because in that case the map isn't updated as you experienced as well).